# How to call JAVA script in HTML file which returns JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, rest

I have the below code which returns as {member:'previous day Data'} when I call the below rest API from browser like:
      http://localhost:3000/prevday (Web server is running on the port 3000)

```
  app.get('/prevday',function(req,res)
    {
            var data ={member:'previous day Data'};
            res.status(200).json({member:'previous day data'});
            //return res.send();

    });
```

I want to write HTML file which displays the result {member:'previous day Data'}. I need to invoke javascript in HTML file. So, I am looking for javascript/ajax file and how can I invoke it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="onPageLoad()">

<div id="demo">
</div>

<script>
function onPageLoad() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/prevday", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```